# fxmlLoader.getController() leading to null pointer exception?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, javafx-2

I'm trying to access an instance of the controller class for the window that loads the fxml. It loads with no errors, but when I try to print the number of accounts using

```
System.out.println("from NAW: "+ NAC.newAccModel.users.getNumAccs());
```

it is giving the nullpointer exception below. (line 36 is the `println`)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at muselogin.newAccountWindow.<init>(newAccountWindow.java:36)
at muselogin.MuseLoginController.initialize(MuseLoginController.java:84)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at muselogin.MuseLogin.start(MuseLogin.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is where I am trying to call the `getController()`

```
public class newAccountWindow extends Application {



    Stage stage = new Stage();
    newAccountController NAC = new newAccountController();

public newAccountWindow(){
    Parent root=null;
    try{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("newAccountWindow.fxml"));
    root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("newAccountWindow.fxml"));
   // fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    NAC = (newAccountController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    System.out.println("from NAW: "+NAC.newAccModel.users.getNumAccs());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(MuseLogin.class.getResource("newAccCSS.css").toExternalForm());        
    stage.setScene(scene);
}
```

here is the controller if it matters

```
public class newAccountController implements Initializable {

    newAccountModel newAccModel;

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML
    private Button createAccount;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField confirmField;
    @FXML
    private Label usernameBlankMessage;
    @FXML
    private Label usernameTakenMessage;
    @FXML
    private Label passwordMessage;


    //counter to check if all 3 conditions are met
    int makeAcc = 0;

    //action event for make account button clicked
    @FXML
    private void createAccountClicked(ActionEvent event) {

        //does account creation stuff

    }

    public int getNumAccs(){
        return newAccModel.users.getNumAccs();
    }

    //required initialize function, initializes model
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        newAccModel = new newAccountModel();

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the constructor for the `newAccountModel()` do?  You don't provide code for it.  Does it associate users with a `newAccountModel` and store a reference in the `users` member of `newAccountModel`?  If not, that is probably the source of your NullPointerException: `users` is null so `users.getItems()` throws a NullPointerException.  See: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)  Please follow [class naming conventions](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an `URL` to the `load` method, you use one of the `static` `load` methods of [`FXMLLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html), which of course cannot store the controller in your `FXMLLoader` instance since there is no information about the instance available.

Since you already specify the `URL` in the `FXMLLoader` constructor, simply use the parameterless `load` method instead:

```
root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Why would having a second declaration of the url cause this to return a null controller?

Comment: @Chase: Writing `fxmlLoader.load(url);` has the same effect as writing `FXMLLoader.load(url)`. Since that load method is `static`, there is no information available that would allow the method to associate the controller instance it creates with the `FXMLLoader` instance you're (not) using. If you want to access properties of the `FXMLLoader` like the controller (assuming it's created during the loading), you need to use one of the non-`static` `load` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NAC = (newAccountController) fxmlLoader.getController();
 System.out.println("from NAW: "+NAC.newAccModel.users.getNumAccs());
```

you cannot to do the `sysout` after the getController. what you are doing is, you creating or initializing  the `newAccModel` in the controller `initilize` method. 
intialize took sometime to gets call. it will call when load complete. but

```
 NAC = (newAccountController) fxmlLoader.getController();
```

after this line, there was load not ready. so its simply giving NPE. please make sure you are access the `newAccModel` after the initialize method executed in the controller